# Spliting text file with conditional operators by python

Tags: python, text

I'm having a huge file, which consists excessive length of transcribed speach for about two days straight. Over 100,000 words I guess.

During transcription, I have separated speaker and sessions by "<-- Name -->" mark into different blocks. My problem is, is it possible to automatically process them into files in a naming convention of name_speach.txt ?

THANKS!!!!

Test cases:

Test case

```
<--测试0-->
这个是一段测试内容，a quick fox jumps over a lazy dog.

<——测试1——>
，a quick fox just over 啊 辣子 dog!！？是吗？

<——测试2——>
这是一段测试用的text，嗯！

<--Test case 3-->
/* sound track lost @153:12.236 -- 153.18.222 */
…
A quick fox jumps over a {lazy|lame} dog.
```

Comment: Depends on how well formatted your data is... What've you tried so far?

Comment: @JonClements each "<-- Name -->" is in a separated line, and there's nothing else in the whole document begin with "<--", neither at the beginning of a line or in the middle of a sentence.

Comment: Could you show some example text.

Comment: @enginefree sure. like this one: <--Don Joe-->\n The quick fox jumps 哦ver a lazy 斗哥！\n <--John Doe-->\n What??? /* it has some CJK chars and semicolons.

Comment: You have example text, so please paste some in your question description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to search every pattern "<-- Name -->" in a text file (100000 words is not very huge for computer memory, I think).

You can use Regular expression for search tags.

In Python, It's something like:

```
import re

NAMETAG = r'\<\-\- (?P<name>.*?) \-\-\>'

# find all nametags in your string
matches = re.findall(NAMETAG, yourtext)

offset_start_list = []
offset_end_list = []
name_list = []

for m in matches:
    name = m.groups()['name']
    name_list.append(name)

    # find content offset after name tag
    offset_start_list.append(m.end() + 1)

    # the last content's end
    offset_end_list.append(m.start())


offset_end_list.pop(0)
offset_end_list.append(len(yourtext))

for name, start, end in zip(name_list, offset_start_list, offset_end_list):
    # save your files here
```